# loading an iframe from a string variable in xulrunner

Tags: xulrunner

I am converting code from using signed JAR files to using an XULRunner based applications.  I am having trouble with code that loads an iframe with html content stored in a javascript variable.

The code looks like this:

```
var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
doc.open();
doc.write(html);
doc.close();
```

The iframe has type="content".  As is, in XULRunner I get an exception in the doc.open() call:

```
[Exception... "The operation is insecure."
   code: "18"
   nsresult: "0x80530012 (SecurityError)"
   location: "chrome://ec4main/content/apps/newsfeedtest/lib.js Line: 938"]
```

If I change the iframe to type="chrome", then it works but this seems like a bad idea because the HTML is not always trusted content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [data URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) instead of `document.write()` (which is indeed insecure and not recommendable):

```js
var wnd = iframe.contentWindow;
wnd.location.href = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(html);
```

Comment: +1 for changing document location to data:text/html

For information, the message "Exception: The operation is insecure" is a bug on Firefox default console (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663406), document.write should work and it works with Firebug console on Firefox and Chromium default console.
In my case, if a web page don't load but you can view page source code, I can force HTML display: document.write(document.body.innerHTML) or document.location = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(document.body.innerHTML)