# Open Window with Pre-Filled HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry about the odd title, I'm not sure how to phrase the question.  Basically, I was wondering if it is possible open a new window and fill it with HTML from the front-end rather than code an actual route, db calls, etc.  (Yep ultra lazy.)  Thinking along these lines...

```
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><body><h1>Y HALO THAR</h1></body>'

window.open(html);
```

Am I just wishing upon a star here?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a new tab/window and write something to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965087/open-a-new-tab-window-and-write-something-to-it)

Comment: Probably!  This was when I was working on a project 7 years ago, so I don't think I need a new answer necessarily.

I wish there was a better way to link duplicates with answers rather than questions.  The question you linked has an accepted answer that no longer works, but if you scroll down you have a working example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49019549/23875

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** this answer no longer works because of [security features implemented](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-58/) that block certain `data:` URIs.

See [Open a new tab/window and write something to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965087/open-a-new-tab-window-and-write-something-to-it/49019549#49019549) for working answer

There is the option to use a [dataurl](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)...

```
window.open('data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><body><h1>Y HALO THAR</h1></body>');
```

Data URIs are currently supported by the following web browsers:

- Firefox and all browsers that use the Mozilla Foundation's Gecko rendering engine
- Safari, Chrome and other WebKit-based browsers
- Opera
- Konqueror
- Internet Explorer 8+ (with certain limitations)

Comment: Thank you sir, fortunately for me I only need to worry about Chrome! :D

Answer (score 6):

The first thing you need to do is make the popup have a variable -

```
var popup = window.open('blankPage.html');
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><body><h1>Y HALO THAR</h1></body>';

popup.document.write(html);
```

Comment: Both fitting answers, unfortunately the dataurl answer was a little more thorough and fits my needs a bit more.  Thanks though!

Comment: Totally understand - that's the great thing about development. There are TONS of ways to do something and each one can meet a specific need. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion to do the following

> ```
> window.open('data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><body><h1>Y HALO THAR</h1></body>');
> ```

no longer works on Chrome due depreciation of the 'data:' allowance.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/chrome-58-deprecations#remove_content-initiated_top_frame_navigations_to_data_urls

If you used this previously, your code will now open a blank window instead.