# Display json in a new browser tab page

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, return

I have been trying for 4 days to solve this problem. But I cannot return json data into a new tab page.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CustomerId() {

var url = "Home/PanelGoster";  // My URL

var veri = {
Id: Id.GetValue(),
};

$.ajax({
url: "/Home/PanelGoster",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(veri),
success: function (mydata) {
if (mydata.error6 == true) {

}
else { // Success

var something = window.open(url, '_blank');  // Problem Here , it does not work
something.focus();   // Problem Here


("#MusterilerGetir").html(mydata);          // Problem Here, should be displayed in a new tab
}
},
error: function () {

}
});
return false;
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult PanelGoster(MyModel model)
    {
    var stringView = RenderRazorViewToString("PartialView", MyModel());
    return Json(stringView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you returning a json if you want to show your view in a new window? Simply return your view;

Comment: How come?Do you have any example ?

Comment: You return a json object, so browser will show only the text of your view. instead of json return PartialView

Comment: What do you recommend ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

```
something = window.open("data:text/json," + encodeURIComponent(mysdata),
                       "_blank");
something.focus();
```

from [Open a new tab/window and write something to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965087/open-a-new-tab-window-and-write-something-to-it)

Comment: I get error in new tab ....This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

Comment: I only see texts in new tab. I can not click nothing.So what do you recommend ?

Comment: it depends on what you need, in your question you said **Display json in new tab page** so I guess your question is answered, is it not ?

Comment: It should be `data:application/json,`, then it will be clickable.