# Displaying form data to new tab

Tags: javascript, forms

I want display the form data to new tab using JavaScript only. This is not proceeding my task. How to achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function showInput() {
            var message_entered =  document.getElementById("user_input").value;

            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = message_entered;
        }    
     </script>   
</head>
<body>    
    <form>
        <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
    </form>

    <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br />
    <label>Your input: </label>
    <p><span id='display'></span> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965087/open-a-new-tab-window-and-write-something-to-it

Comment: I fixed some typos and updated tags and remove code request. StackOverflow is not the right place request code. Please post what you have tried so far and clearly mention why it is not meeting your needs such as errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = "<p>This is new tab'</p><br/>"+message_entered;
newWindow = window.open("data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(data),
                   "_blank", "width=200,height=100");
newWindow.focus();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jvttLcnh/4/)

Comment: Note that this does not work in certain browsers, due to them not supporting "navigable content" (ie. HTML et al.) in `data:` URIs.