# View Javascript JSON Object on the Browser

Tags: javascript, json, browser

I have this Json object on JavaScript:

```
    var case= {
        description: $("#a").val(),
        start: document.getElementById("b").textContent,
        end: document.getElementById("c").textContent,
        frequency: $("#d").val(),
        deployment: $("#e").val(),
    }
    mainFile.events.push({"id": Object.keys(manifest.events).length, case});
    localStorage.setItem('LocalStor', JSON.stringify(mainFile));
```

Every time I run this function I add/push a new object the the `mainFile` object and store it in the local storage.
I can view the whole object from console and it is working, but what I want is to display it on a new tab of the browser, just like opening a JSON file on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to base 64:

```
window.location = "data:application/json;base64,"+btoa( JSON.stringify(mainFile) );
```

Comment: I got this error: Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:application/json,eyJldmVudHMiOlt7Im...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = window.open("data:text/json," + encodeURIComponent(mainFile),
                       "_blank");
data.focus();
```

from [Open a new tab/window and write something to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965087/open-a-new-tab-window-and-write-something-to-it)

Comment: I did open a new window but still empty,
btw, wont work with Adblock running on the browser