# save the google charts into images and open them to a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I take a tutorial to print Google Charts from this document.
[Google Charts Documentary](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing)
But I have some problems that I want to ask, maybe anyone can help me?

1. How to save chart as image directly when i click link button?
2. How to directly open the image to new tab when i click "print" button? I tried adding "target = blank" but it didn't work.

the real code

```
document.getElementById('png').outerHTML = '<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">Printable version</a>';
```

and im trying to add target='_blank' here

```
    document.getElementById('png').outerHTML = '<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '" target="blank">Printable version</a>';
```

this my fiddle for testing the code

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adityads/sxqypbwr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't open a new tab with a data-uri URL, [see this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967627/745121).

You will have to use `window.open` and then write content into it.

Answer (score -1):

For your first issue, you can simply add a download attribute to your  tag. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp

For the second issue, there was just a small problem with the quotation mark choice and placement. In this case, I just had to use double quotes around _blank instead, see below. A properly set up IDE can help with small syntax issues like this by highlighting different types.

```
  document.getElementById('png').outerHTML =
 '<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '" target="_blank">Printable version</a>';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but 1. is working, and 2 is not working

Comment: Okay, I've just changed the solution. Please try it out now, this is working in my home environment.

Comment: there is no significant difference between your answers and my questions. both of them use target = 'blank'. and as I said before that target = "blank" does not work for me.