# How to open web page returned by ajax call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe, embed

I have an ajaxcall which returns an html page to me in the response. I want to open this in a new window. How to make this work?

[image]

`console.log(data)` basically prints the entire html content as if it were a single string

Comment: Why Ajax?? If you want to open a page in a new window, use a link to the source of the HTML and `target="_blank"`

Comment: Unfortunately I can only share an api. How do I trigger javascript on client side then?

Comment: If you can do console.log you can do what is suggested in the answer too

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var tab = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
tab.document.write(data); 
tab.document.close();
```

> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49019549/12968095

Comment: I can only give them the rest api. How can I call the javascript you wrote in that situation?